# What would the truth table for ¬(⊥⊻(a∨¬a)) be?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I've been stumped on this question for a good 2-3 hours with barely any progress and none of my texts have illuminated any help.

$$¬\left(⊥⊻(a∨¬a)\right)$$

As far as I can tell it isn't a wff, so how can I create a truth table for it? Is it even possible? I'm confused on what to do with the negation, falsum and exclusive disjunct.

Thanks.

Comment: Is $(a \lor \neg a)$ always true?

Comment: @zkutch Yes, whether a is true or false, (a∨¬a) will be true. How would I approach the rest of the statement after that? That is what is really stumping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a∨¬a)$ is always "$\text{true}$".

If in $¬\left(⊥⊻(a∨¬a)\right)$ symbol $⊥$ we understand as "$\text{false}$", the inside brackets is $\text{false} ⊻ \text{true}$. Hope rest is obvious?

Comment: Haha, thank you so much. It really was staring me right in the eyes. Makes complete sense now!